# Using required_without on Nested form

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-validation

I have a request in the format

```
array:2 [▼
  "_token" => "Lqn3XPvbdhLC8iqs461xSrGYPmxmSv4PGCqH7LJQ"
  "branch" => array:16 [▼
    "customer_company_id" => "5"
    "is_main" => "true"
  ]
]
```

I need to validate the form in the following way:

1. If customer_company_id is present `name` is not required
2. If customer_company_id is not present `name` is required

My FormRequest looks like

```
public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'branch' => [
                'is_main' => [
                    'required',
                    'boolean'
                ],
                'customer_company_id' => [
                    'required_without:branch.name'
                ],
            ],
        ];
}
```

it throws the following error

```
Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateRequiredWithout:branch.name does not exist
```

Comment: I'm curious where you found this  kind of validation documented. In the docs validating arrays requires the use of the dot notation e.g. `'branch.is_main' => ..., 'branch.customer_company_id' => ....` but from your message this also seems to work (though I would try using just `name` rather than `branch.name`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this?

```php
return [
    'branch.name' => 'required_without:branch.customer_company_id',
    'branch.is_main' => 'required|boolean',
    'branch.customer_company_id' => 'required_without:branch.name',
```